# как узнать, является ли путь настоящим?

Tags: python, tkinter, pathlib

Я уже пробовал это:

```
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

if Path(input_file_location.get()).is_file():
        
    messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Данные не являются действительным путём")
```

Но если я ввожу не верный путь, то ничего не происходит.

Comment: Так нужно обратное же условие проверять, а не прямое: `if not Path....` Так что у вас всё правильно работает.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ, нужно в место `.is_file` написать `is_dir`

Comment: is_file и is_dir проверяют разные вещи. Вы точно уверены, что вам нужно именно то, что проверяет is_dir?

Comment: Если нужно проверить, что путь существует, нужно использовать метод `.exists()`, вот пример с сайта, который вам в первом комментарии дали: https://www.guru99.com/python-check-if-file-exists.html#pathlibPath-exists . `is_file` и `is_dir` проверяют являться ли путь файлом или директорией соответственно. Но то что путь не является файлом или не является директорией не означает, что путь некорректен.

Comment: мне нужно было конкретно знать являются ли данные настоящим путём, для имени файла у меня в программе было отдельное поле ввода